# Software Design Pattern for multiuser-editing in "Realtime"

Tags: java, android, design-patterns, real-time, multi-user

I´m looking for a Software Design Pattern which solves the problems of editing a document by different users at the same time. I want to use it for an android app. Up to now I just found the [Google Realtime API](https://developers.google.com/drive/realtime/overview) but this doesn´t seem what I´m looking for because it´s for websites. Currently I´m thinking that i should use the [observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) and some method to check wether change have been made and if where.

Answer (score 3):

Consider implement your design using ReadWriteLock interface. If the readers should get the updated document (if someone has updated while other reading), you can use observer pattern to notify readers once the document is being updated by writer.

```
public class Document {

    private ReadWriteLock lock;
    // other fields and methods are omitted for brevity

    public Document(){
        lock=new ReentrantReadWriteLock();
    }

    public void write(Object msg){
    lock.writeLock().lock();
    // write document
    }

    public Object read(){
    lock.readLock().lock();
    // write document
    return "reading";
    }
}


public class Reader implements Runnable {

    private Document document;

    public Reader (Document document){
        this.document=document;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        document.read();
    }
}


public class Writer implements Runnable {

    private Document document;
    private Object msg;

    public Writer(Document document,Object msg){
        this.document=document;
        this.msg=msg;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        document.write(msg);
    }
}
```

For more details on ReadWriteLock take a look at:
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReadWriteLock.html